# How to use `onComplete()` method in typed.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typed.js

I have seen the [documentation](http://mattboldt.github.io/typed.js/docs/) of `typed.js` about `onComplete()`:

> All typing is complete
>
> onComplete(self: Typed)
>
> Parameters self (Typed)

it isn't obvious  enough. After completion I want to delay 10s before start typing again and I can't use `startDelay:10s` property for this purpose either because it delays 10s even before start typing.

Here is a sample Code:

```
  <div class="container">
      <p>This is an <span id="typed"></span> website.</p>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.11"></script>

    <script>
      var typed = new Typed("#typed", {
        strings: ["awesome", "interesting"],
        stringsElement: null,
        typeSpeed: 20,
        startDelay: 1500,
        backSpeed: 20,
 }
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
    var typed = new Typed("#typed", {
        strings: ["awesome", "interesting"],
        stringsElement: null,
        typeSpeed: 20,
        startDelay: 1500,
        backSpeed: 20,

        // callback on complete
        onComplete: function(self) { prettyLog('onCmplete ' + self) }
    });
</script>
```